# Show only specific categories in permalinks for custom post type in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I tried to ask this question in the Wordpress Devlopment network with no success, I'm trying to display only 3 specific categories in permalinks for custom-post-type categories.

Right now the permalinks structure (that is the structure given by [the theme i'm using](https://themeforest.net/item/recipe-wp-theme-for-recipes/10600852) and that i'm modifying through a child theme)is as follows:

```
www.myfoodblog.com/recipes/the-post-title/
         ^            ^           ^    
       root   custom-post-type  title
```

some post are under 3 categories that i would like to display in permalinks which are `restaurant`, `users` and `admin` to get something like this

```
www.myfoodblog.com/recipes/restaurant/the-post-title/

www.myfoodblog.com/recipes/users/the-post-title/

www.myfoodblog.com/recipes/admin/the-post-title/
```

leaving the original structure for posts that are not in those categories.

I tried using [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalinks-customizer/) but it will display the custom post type category for all posts.

I also tried to follow the instructions provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024040/getting-wordpress-to-automatically-show-category-permalink-for-only-specific-cat) but it's not working, no changes are made in the permalinks structure.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a plugin for your custom post-types or did you define the custom post-type yourself? I've achieved this on a site I'm currently working on but it's all custom code

Comment: @Daniel I'm not using any plugin at the moment and the CPT is defined by the theme i'm using.

Comment: Okay, so what is your permalink structure like? I'd suggest '/%category%/%postname%/' Wordpress should serve the URL like this: domain/CPT/category/postname

Comment: @Daniel Yeah the structure is exactly like that and it outputs domain/cpt/post-title. I'm trying to have domain/cpt/category/post-title but ONLY if the post is in one of 3 specific categories. Otherwise the structure should remain the same.

Comment: I think what you're looking to do is outside of my expertise and experience, let's hope someone else can shed light on this..

Comment: I think you need to take a look at Wordpress function `add_rewrite_rule` https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule than after you use this, you'll need to resave your permalink structure in the backend admin settings in order to flush permalinks to test it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to work with both `post_type_link` and add a `rewrite rule`

```
function recipes_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
    $post = get_post( $id );
    if ( is_object( $post ) ){
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'recipe-category' );
        foreach($terms as $term) {
            if( $term->slug == 'restaurants' || $term->slug == 'users'){
                return str_replace( site_url()."/recipes" , site_url()."/recipes/".$term->slug , $post_link );
            }
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'recipes_post_link', 1, 3 );

function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^recipes/(.+)/(.+)', 'index.php?recipe=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Comment: That's what i was looking for! It works perfectly! I didn't know about the `add_rewrite_rule` function and it seems to be necessary

Answer (score 2):

## [Create Post Type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

```
add_action( 'init', 'codex_recipes_init' );
/**
 * Register a recipes post type.
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type
 */
function codex_recipes_init() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Recipes', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Recipe', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Recipes', 'admin menu', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Recipe', 'add new on admin bar', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'recipe', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Recipe', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Recipe', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Recipe', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Recipe', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Recipes', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Recipes', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Recipes:', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No recipes found.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No recipes found in Trash.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'recipes/%type%' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => 'recipes',
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
    );

    register_post_type( 'recipes', $args );
}
```

**Important:** look on rewrite rule: `'rewrite'=> array( 'slug' => 'recipes/%type%' ),`

## [Create Custom Taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)

```
// hook into the init action and call create_recipes_taxonomies when it fires
add_action( 'init', 'create_recipes_taxonomies', 0 );

function create_recipes_taxonomies() {

    // Add new taxonomy, NOT hierarchical (like tags)
    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Type', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Type', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Types', 'textdomain' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Types', 'textdomain' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Types', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item'                => null,
        'parent_item_colon'          => null,
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Type', 'textdomain' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Type', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Type', 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Type Name', 'textdomain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate types with commas', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove types', 'textdomain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used types', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'No types found.', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Types', 'textdomain' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_admin_column'     => true,
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var'             => true,
        'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'type' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'type', 'recipes', $args );
}
```

## [Add Filter Post Type Link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_type_link)

```
function recipes_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
    $post = get_post( $id );  
    if ( is_object( $post ) ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'type' );
        if( $terms ){
            return str_replace( '%type%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;  
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'recipes_post_link', 1, 3 );
```

**Important:** After all go to permalink options and reset it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. The Post Type and the Custom Taxonomy are already defined by the theme and are named respectively `recipes` and `recipe-category` So looks like i would need to use just your `recipes_post_link` function but it doesnt work. Also it looks like it would work for every category while i asked to only work with SOME category, something like `if ($terms == 'restaurant' || $terms == 'users' || $terms == 'admin') { do stuff }`